# 2-3% packet loss shown on a node when I run a traceroute. How can I fix it?

Tags: networking, gaming

Here are some WinMTR's that I have run:

[image: Screenshot one]

[image: Screenshot two]

I have packet loss on `213.46.175.254`. Both Virgin Media (my ISP) and Blizzard (they make the game I'm trying to play, Overwatch) are saying they cannot fix the problem. What can I do?

The packet loss causes input delay in the game I'm playing according to Blizzard tech support.

Comment: I guess I am not sure what you can do, it is clearly outside of your control... Welcome to the Internet! There is no guaranteed quality of service in the "cloud", you are most likely dealing with some router queuing in route somewhere between your ISP and Blizzard, which you have zero possible influence in. Sorry, but no one here can really assist you.

Comment: oh, ok :( if i complain to my isp could they fix it?

Comment: You can try, but honestly I deal with this all the time and the chances complaining to your ISP will help are near zero since it appears from your trace routes to be outside if your ISP's network and in a intermediate carrier network. Best bet would likely be find a good, low latency VPN that has a better route to Blizzard, which would be purely trial and error.

Comment: There is nothing to fix. As you can see, nodes further along the path do *not* display this package loss. This statistic simply means the host in question cannot be bothered to send ICMP Time Exceeded packets every time. Your latency with the target host is very good.